# Saving toggled elements and to local storage in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying in my Web application to toggle elements with a significant button.

The text in the button changes when the elements fade in, and changes again when they are hidden.

Here's an [JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/KCj3r/)!, that I found.

```
<div class="ISBody">
<h5>Header</h5>
<div class="ISTopLink"><a href="#ISTop">Return to Top</div>
<div class="ISHide"><a href="#" class="hideLink">Hide Products - </a></div>
<hr>
<div id="pos" style="display: block;">
  <div class="ISProductBody">
   <div class="ISSubHead"><A HREF="#">Prodcut Name</A></div>
  <div class="ISList">
   <ul>
    <li>Text here</li>
    <li>Text here</li>
    <li>Text here</li>
    <li>Text here</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

$(".hideLink").on("click", function(){
if($(this).text()=="Hide Products - ")
{
    $(this).text("Show Products - ");
} else {
    $(this).text("Hide Products - ");
}
$(".ISProductBody").toggle(); 

return false;
});
```

How can I save the changed state to local storage, so that when I refresh the page, it does not go to its first state! Like for the Elements that are shown/hidden and the changed text in the button or link.

I am thankful for every tip or solution! Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to my problem and works perfectly!!

Here's [The solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49617535/save-changed-text-to-button-on-toggling-elements-in-localstorage-javascript/49617828?noredirect=1#comment86243924_49617828)!

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Just store the current state in `localStorage` using `.setItem()` and on page load get the current state and act accordingly.

```js
$(".hideLink").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "Hide Products - ") {
    $(this).text("Show Products - ");
    localStorage.setItem("hidden", true);
  } else {
    $(this).text("Hide Products - ");
    localStorage.setItem("hidden", false);
  }
  $(".ISProductBody").toggle();

  return false;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var hidden = localStorage.getItem("hidden");

  if (hidden) {
    $(".hideLink").text("Show Products - ");
    $(".ISProductBody").toggle();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ISBody">
  <h5>Header</h5>
  <div class="ISTopLink"><a href="#ISTop">Return to Top</a></div>
  <div class="ISHide"><a href="#" class="hideLink">Hide Products - </a></div>
  <hr>
  <div id="pos" style="display: block;">
    <div class="ISProductBody">
      <div class="ISSubHead">
        <A HREF="#">Prodcut Name</A>
      </div>
      <div class="ISList">
        <ul>
          <li>Text here</li>
          <li>Text here</li>
          <li>Text here</li>
          <li>Text here</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is only changing the text to the other one, on refresh it is going to the next state

Comment: I believe `localStorage` doesn't work in jsfiddle. Did you try it on your own page?

Comment: Yes, I tried it on my page also, and it set the value to the one saved in the localStorage :(

Comment: Sebastian Speitel did you test it? and if it worked with you?

Comment: Did you try to `console.log(hidden)` after the `localStorage.getItem()`?

Comment: Yes it is working perfectly :) but the changes to the text in the button  are not saved :(

Comment: js fiddle supports the localStorage